# Can I make the inventory to be updated when clicking the item in another GUI, individually?

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm making a GUI for my parkour server, but I have a problem:

[image]

([YT link](https://youtu.be/BgBMzQ_9XHU), can expire)

As you can see, other player's GUI also updated when I click next page.

I also tried set the owner of Inventory not to be null (so individually), but it just showed the mpty GUI.

How can I fix this? I searched a lot and tried lots of thing but couldn't find the answer.

```java
// the showed inventory
Inventory basicInv = Bukkit.createInventory(null, 54, "Basic Jumps");

@EventHandler
public void clickInv(InventoryClickEvent event) {

    Player player = (Player) event.getWhoClicked();

    if (event.getClickedInventory() == null) return;

    if (event.getCurrentItem() == null) return;
    if (event.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta() == null) return;
    if (event.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().getDisplayName() == null) return;

    if (event.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals(" ")) {
        event.setCancelled(true);
    }

    switch (event.getClickedInventory().getName()) {
        case "OneJump Menu":
            if (event.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals(basicName)
                    && event.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().getLore().equals(Collections.singletonList(ChatColor.GRAY + "Includes very historical and original jumps."))) {
                player.openInventory(basicInv);
                basicInventorySet1(player, basicInv);
                event.setCancelled(true);

                plugin.getPlayerConfig().set("Player." + player.getUniqueId() + ".PlayingJumpType", "basicjump");
                plugin.savePlayerConfig();
            } else if (event.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals(DisplayName)
                    || event.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals(basicName)) {
                event.setCancelled(true);
            } else if (event.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals(" ")) {
                event.setCancelled(true);
            } else {
                event.setCancelled(true);
                player.closeInventory();
                sendMessage(player, "§cComing soon!", "현재 개발 중입니다!");
            }
            break;
        case "Basic Jumps":
            if (event.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals(pg2Name)) {
                event.setCancelled(true);
                basicInventorySet2(player, basicInv);
            } else if (event.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals(pg1Name)) {
                event.setCancelled(true);
                basicInventorySet1(player, basicInv);
            } else if (event.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals(pg3Name)) {
                event.setCancelled(true);
                basicInventorySet3(player, basicInv);
            }
            break;
    }

}
```

Full source: [BasicInv.java](https://sourceb.in/OBKmC3xU3a) [OjMenu.java](https://sourceb.in/muZ43oOnpx)

Comment: It's off-topic but the `OneJump Menu` will not work, the inventory that you open isn't the same as you edit. Also, I think some important code is missing to solve the issue, here it's clearly impossible to have this problem

Comment: https://sourceb.in/OBKmC3xU3a
https://sourceb.in/muZ43oOnpx

Full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you are create ONE inventory, and using it for EVERYONE. So each time that the player open the inventory, it will open the "shared" inventory.

You are doing this:

```java
Inventory inv = Bukkit.createInventory(null, 54, "Inventory"); // create one instance

public void show(Player p) {
   p.openInventory(inv); // everyone open same inventory instance
}
```

So everything will using same instance.

In your first code example, that was better :

```java
public Inventory createInventory() {
   return Bukkit.createInventory(null, 54, "Inventory"); // create a new inventory
}

public void showBasicJump(Player p) { // show an inventory to the given player
   Inventory myInv = createInventory(); // create a new inv, for thi splayer
   myInv.setItem(0, new ItemStack(Material.STICK); // set item
   basicInventorySet1(player, myInv); // call your method that change all items
   p.openInventory(myInv); // final inventory
}

public void updateBasicJumpInv(InventoryClickEvent e, Player player) { // before this, you made all check about inv
   Inventory openInv = e.getClickedInventory(); // get the current opened inv. Can also work with player.getOpenInventory()
   basicInventorySet1(player, openInv);
   p.updateInventory(); // update player inv
}
```

That will create a new instance each time that you will open a new inventory.

Comment: Uh, am I wrote right? The GUI is empty when I opened
https://sourceb.in/Z4gpPJ8tUL

Comment: here the player have openned an inventory, and you create a new one inventory and you are setting item to the new one inventory. So you have to use `basicInventorySet2(player, e.getClickedInventory())`

Comment: I tried using that strategy, but how can I open the basic inventory? the show method works but basicInventorySet2(player, e.getClickedInventory()) seems like doesn't work.